# Build a list out of a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to parse a jenkins API to get the job name and job status and build individual dictionaries for each of the respective job and state and then add these individual dictionaries into a final list.
So far what i have done is

```
url = "https://" + self.jenkins_instance + "/api/json"
urllib3.disable_warnings(category=InsecureRequestWarning)
res = requests.get(
    url,
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth(
        self.user,
        self.api
    ),
    verify=False
)
jobs = json.loads(res.text).get('jobs')
for j in jobs:
    job_name = j.get('name')
    job_state = j.get('color')
    self.my_dict['job_name'] = job_name
    self.my_dict['job_state'] = job_state
    print(self.my_dict)
self.my_list.append(self.my_dict)
print(self.my_list)
```

`url, user and api` are already defined values in the rest of my code.

I got my values and i am building a dictionary out of those values but when i add these dictionaries to my final list, it does not have all the data, it only has the last dictionary value.
I expect the list to have all the values of the dictionaries.

If i indent my code to append the dictionary within the foor loop, the list has all the same elements.

How shall i change my code to get the expected output.

Comment: By indenting `self.my_list.append(self.my_dict)`

Comment: @nightgaunt sure about that? Have you tested it?

Comment: @nightgaunt That is incorrect/incomplete. It happens because he only add the one dictionary, but even if his indentation would be correct, he would have a list of references to 1 dict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`self.my_dict` is a mutable object. So for each job, you overwrite the job_name and job_state

```
for j in jobs:
    summary = {"job_name": j.gen("name"), "job_state": j.get('color')}
    self.my_list.append(summary)
```

There are more elegant ways to do this (list comprehensions or generators) but this fixes your bug